# Lighttpd init script doesn't work on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, lighttpd, init.d, debian-wheezy

[EDIT]
I have found why it did not work, I just had to add the directive

```
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
```

to the lighttpd.conf file.

---

I can't figure out why the lighttpd init script doesn't work to stop the server. I'm running Debian 7 Wheezy and Lighttpd 1.4.31. My system is also up-to-date.

When issuing:

```
# /etc/init.d/lighttpd stop
[ ok ] Stopping web server: lighttpd.
```

But then lighttpd is still running:

```
# ps aux | grep lighttpd
root      2024  0.0  0.2  70696  1184 ?        S    15:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
root      2428  0.0  0.1   7832   880 pts/0    S+   15:27   0:00 grep lighttpd
```

When removing "quiet" from the stop part of the script to get more details which gives:

```
if start-stop-daemon --stop --retry 30 --oknodo \
            --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
```

I get this output:

```
# /etc/init.d/lighttpd stop
[....] Stopping web server: lighttpdNo /usr/sbin/lighttpd found running; none killed.
. ok
```

whereas /usr/sbin/lighttpd is actually running as shown by the ps command.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you add the solution as an answer (and accept it) instead of updating your question?